# How can I pass a variable into a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive:

```
app.directive('dropdown', ['$timeout',function ($timeout) {
    return {
        require: '^ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="dropdownDirective" class="btn-group" dropdown>' +
        '<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="ngDisabled" dropdown-toggle>' +
        '{{ items[ngModel].name }}' +
        '<span class="caret"></span>' +
        '</button>' +
        '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role ="menu" aria-label="dLabel">' +
        '<li ng-repeat="item in items">' +
        '<a href="#" ng-bind="item.name" ng-click="select(item)" >< / a >' +
        '</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=', // selected item
            items: '=',   // items to select from
            ngDisabled: '=',
            ngChange: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope: any, element, attrs, ngModelCtlr) {
            // selection changed handler
            scope.select = function (item, ngModel) {
                scope.ngModel = item.id;
                $timeout(scope.ngChange, 0);
                ngModelCtlr.$setDirty();
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

I call it like this:

```
<dropdown ng-model="phs.phrases[row.index].posId"
          items="phs.phrasePosShortNames">
</dropdown>
```

What I would like to do is to be able to call the directive and pass in a parameter called noButtonBorder.  Then I would like the class "noBorder" to be added to the button if that parameter is passed.

Comment: Uhm. Same way as you already did with the attributes defined in `scope`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope: {
        ngModel: '=', // selected item
        items: '=',   // items to select from
        ngDisabled: '=',
        ngChange: '&',
        noButtonBorder: '='
    },
link: function (scope: any, element, attrs, ngModelCtlr) {
        // selection changed handler
        if(noButtonBorder){
       attrs.class="noBorder";
         }
        };
```